# How do you return a view inside of a json response in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

I am implementing a simple registration form with Laravel.  On a failure, it should return a json response:

```
{"success":"false", "message":"Could not log in newly registered user"}`
```

This works as expected.  If a successful registration and login takes place, I want to return:

```
{"success":"true", "message":$html}
```

In this case, the `$html` would be created with a view.  The important parts of this are as follows:

```
if(Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'))))
{
    $html = View::make('welcome_new_user', array('first_name' => Input::get('first_name')));
    return Response::json(array('success' => 'true', 'message' => $html));
}
else
{
    return Response::json(array('success' => 'false', 'message' => 'Could not log in newly created user.'));
}
```

On failure, I get the expected response.  On success, I get the `"success":"true"`, but an empty `message`.  I've echoed out the `$html` immediately before the return, and it contains the html expected.  Why is the message empty in the return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`View::make()` actually returns an `Illuminate\View\View` object. The reason why surrounding the variable in double quotes worked is because doing that implicitly calls `$html->__toString()`, which calls the `render()` method and returns the html represented by the `View` object.

The explicit way to get the html from the `View` would be to call the `render()` method directly (`$html->render()`).

Answer (score 1):

The `$html` is what is returned from the `View::make()`.  For it to be returned in the response, it needs to be enclosed in quotes.  The working solution is as follows:

```
if(Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'))))
{
    $html = View::make('welcome_new_user', array('first_name' => Input::get('first_name')));
    return Response::json(array('success' => 'true', 'message' => "$html"));
}
else
{
    return Response::json(array('success' => 'false', 'message' => 'Could not log in newly created user.'));
}
```

Note the `'message' => "$html"`.